# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, mysql, apache, java-ee, tomcat

Всем привет. Было все норм. Все работало. Теперь выдает ошибку Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.
уже удалял сервер,не знаю что делать!

Comment: Старайтесь формулировать вопросы менее сумбурно. Просмотрите весь лог старта, там наверняка есть ошибки с описанием источника проблемы. Приведите тексты ошибок в вопросе.

Comment: вы случайно не знаете ,где может находится такая директория ? <workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources

Comment: нашел вот решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start-without-stack-trace-whi

Comment: но не могу понять где эта папка ёмаё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение было найдено ! у меня в проекте нет аннотаций типа :
                        @WebServlet("/AdminServlet") 
поэтому решил прописать все .jsp страницы в файле web.xml 
вот пример одной страницы :

```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>footer</servlet-name>
     <jsp-file>/WebContent/footer.jsp</jsp-file> //это ОЧЕНЬ важно !! из-за неверного пути и падала ошибка Апача !! 
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>footer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/footer</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

либо решение использовать только аннотации